# Array is behaving differently in Nodejs and browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object

I have this snippet of code :

```
let a = {};
a.x = 'John';

let b = [];
b['y'] = a;
console.log(b);

a.x = 'Dan';
console.log(b)
```

I ran this code in NodeJS using command line and ran it in Chrome browser console.

The result : in NodeJS, the result was  [ y: { x: 'John' } ]
[ y: { x: 'Dan' } ] [NodeJS result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oaewv.png)

The result : in Chrome browser console, the result was : [ y: { x: 'Dan' } ] [ y: { x: 'Dan' } ] [Browser result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quSHM.png)

Why it is giving different results in node and browser console? Can anyone please explain what is really going on here?

Comment: `b['y'] = a;` is incorrect syntax

Comment: @FlashThunder I found that fishy as well, but apparently there is no syntax error here since an array is an object.

Comment: yeah, but that's why it is being interpreted differently, as it's not a valid javascript

Comment: The Chrome result is what I expect. I'm surprised to see the claimed result [in Node.js](https://repl.it/join/uxcrgffp-codeguru).

Comment: @FlashThunder Why is it not valid JS? An array is an object and can therefore be subscripted with a string. Changing to the equivalent `b.y = a` gives the same results.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice it is not the same object... try `a.push()` and `b.push()`

Comment: @FlashThunder What is not the same as what object? And how does `push()` have anything to do with this question? That is a completely different operation than the assignment asked about here.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice because array is an object as well in the meaning of 'typeof', but totally differntly defined

Comment: @FlashThunder Ok, but if this was invalid syntax, then we should get a syntax error, right? not actual output.

Comment: yeah but being an object doesn't mean much, prototypes are different, it won't call a syntax error as every object can have params assigned that way, doesn't mean that it's a valid way to do that in the case of array, for example on older firefox with more strict javascript it does return an error

Answer (score 4):

The chrome browser console shows you the live value of the object, that is it updates the values displayed as it changes, the node js console doesn't do this.
So when you did the first console.log it would show the same as in node but when you changes the value of `a` it was updated in the first console.log.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things happening here.

1. Chrome console by default shows unexpanded object inside an array - `[y: {...}]`
2. Chrome console seems to track the value of the variable and show the updated value when you click to expand the log.

If you need to check that logs are in fact the same as in node.js, you can use `JSON.stringify()` or `console.table()` instead of `console.log()`

Comment: Another way would be to just log `b.y`